# Sitecore: Shared session on CM server

Tags: sitecore, session-state

[This page](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/session_state/walkthrough_configure_a_shared_session_state_database_using_the_sql_server_provider) on the Sitecore documentation site notes that "Shared session state is not supported on content management servers" but it does not mention why. Does anybody know why that is?

We have a test-setup with two servers where one server is a dedicated content delivery server and the other is a combined content delivery/content management server (a combined server was chosen to keep license costs down). We hope to find out if shared out-proc session will be working in this setup.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, CM servers do not support shared session states, i.e. they do not support `StateServer` or `SQLServer`. CM servers have to be configured `InProc`. One reason for this is controlling edits. If the content editor was being bounced between CM servers, some data may not be preserved correctly.

Since you are sharing servers for a CM and CD, you will not be able to use out of proc.

From a security standpoint, I do not recommend sharing your CD and CM server. Your CM server should not be available in a production environment. The cost of an additional CD license out weighs the cost of exposing the CM server.

Edit: Starting with Sitecore 6.5 U5, out of proc session state became experimental. Which means you can't get support for it.

I am adding the versions to the answer for CM support. **NOTE: support is only experimental and I do not recommend using it on your Sitecore CM servers**
According to the Sitecore Knowledgebase https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/901069, the following support notes have been abstracted for CM servers:

- **Sitecore 6.5.0 Update-4** and earlier - only `InProc`
- **Sitecore 6.5.0 Update-5** (Service Pack-1) - "experimental support for using Sitecore Clients with SqlServer, StateServer, and other out-of-process session-state modes since CMS 6.5.0 Update-5.
  Core features such as content editing and publishing should work as expected, but we are aware of a number of issues that have not yet been addressed, so the feature can be used for evaluation of this functionality, but is not considered production-ready yet."
- **Sitecore 7.0 Update-3** - Further fixes
- **Sitecore 7.5 Initial Release** - Serialization errors found
  `ERROR Application error.
  Exception: System.Web.HttpException
  Message: Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
  Source: System.Web
  at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer)
  at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer)
  at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)
  ...`
- **Sitecore 7.5 Update-1** - fixed serialization and and additional fixes

Comment: Do you know what will actually happen if I activate out-proc on the CM server? The CM server will not be available in production - this is only in our test-setup.

Comment: Please see my addition comments in the answer